# How to select checkbox based on another checkbox state in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

Below is my scenario.

> I have 2 checkboxes named A & B which are inside the ng-repeat element. The possible states of these 2 checkboxes are
>
> 1. When A is truthy, B can be either truthy or falsey
> 2. When A is falsey, B can never be truthy.

Below is my code which I tried with ng-checked, but as ng-checked doesn't allow ng-model along with it, I couldn't come up with a solution.

> NOTE: I need to capture both these 2 checkboxes state in my Model

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in editor.vehicles">                                        
      <td>
         <v-check name="A" ng-model="vehicle.modelA"></v-check>
      </td>
      <td>
         <v-check name="B" ng-model="vehicle.modelB" ng-checked="vehicle.modelA"></v-check>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Above code uses a directive `v-check` which is nothing but a checkbox.

EDIT:
The template of my `v-check` directive:
    `<label class='checkbox-inline'><input ng-model='ngModel' type='checkbox'>{{text}}</label>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your checkbox `<input>` tag is not wrapped around a `<div>` in your directive? In that case `ng-checked` might not work.

Comment: @ccg - Edited my question to include the template from the directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my solution to the problem, which also fixes the scenario as suggested by @entre in his comment.

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in editor.vehicles">                                        
  <td>
     <v-check name="A" ng-model="vehicle.modelA" ng-click="vehicle.modelB=false"></v-check>
  </td>
  <td>
     <v-check name="B" ng-model="vehicle.modelB" ng-disabled="!vehicle.modelA"></v-check>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

use ng-disabled for B:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in editor.vehicles">                                        
      <td>
         <v-check name="A" ng-model="vehicle.modelA"></v-check>
      </td>
      <td>
         <v-check name="B" ng-model="vehicle.modelB" ng-disabled="!vehicle.modelA"></v-check>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I already tested this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example54-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `ng-disabled="!vehicle.modelA"`, right?